After running pivot_root, how do you remove put_old?
I'm trying to replicate how a container is made for academic purposes so I've created some namespaces on an ubuntu VM and I'm trying to pivot_root into a busybox filesystem on the hard drive. I've run pivot root successfully like this.
# pivot_root . old_root

Which worked fine, but now the entire old filesystem is accessible via the path /old_root which I'd like to remove.
By running df I can see there is a bunch of mounts there like /old_root/run/lock, /old_root/dev/shm, and /old_root/run/user/1000. I've tried unmounting them like this but I get this error no matter which mount I try.
# umount -l /old_root/run/user/1000
umount: can't unmount /old_root/run/user/1000: Invalid argument

What do I need to do to make sure /old_mount is not accessible?
